# Simple Editor with PCRE support

Tags: regex, editor

Up to now I use `gedit` to do search+replace of text I copy+paste.

But I prefer PCRE (Python .-) compatible regular expressions)

Wanted features:

- open source
- GUI (not terminal based (ncurses))
- PCRE for search+replace
- Should start fast
- Available for Ubuntu 14.04 or greater.

Comment: As you explicitly wrote "no ncurses", I'm just leaving a comment on what I use: MidnightCommander's built-in editor (`mcedit`) supports this, and I use it a lot. But that's "terminal based (ncurses)", so it doesn't fit your requirements (it does fit all requirements but this one, that is).

Comment: If there is an easy way to add a terminal application like mcedit with Super-A (unity: search applications), then I could use it. But AFAIK there is no easy way to add terminal applications there ... I installed mcedit. I can open mc, but super-a does not show "mcedit" - sad.

Comment: No idea. Unity was the first thing I kicked when I last installed Ubuntu a couple of years ago (not my concept of a desktop). Answers on this might be found at our sister site AskUbuntu, if needed :)

Comment: I use [nedit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nedit/) on Ubuntu 14.04. It has regex but I'm not sure if uses Python PCRE.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Editra](http://www.editra.org/) which is:

- Small & Fast to load
- Cross Platform (Linux, OS-X & Windows)
- GUI wxPython
- Python 2.6/2.7
- Open Source & Gratis
- Uses python regular expressions
- Provides syntax highlighting for numerous languages & code folding

[image: On Windows]
[image]

Comment: I have never heard from "Editra". The features look good. No update since two years, I guess it is stable :-)